# WordPress AJAX - Returns entire HTML markup in response

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get an AJAX call working on WordPress and cannot get it to work at all. I've looked at some other answers and they must have some relevance as it's clearly the same issue, but in my scenario; I've no idea what's going wrong.

This is the code that I'm including on the page.

The PHP is included through require and is definitely working fine. The JavaScript is also included correctly because it's returning something (just not the right thing).

***JS***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.button').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            url: MY_PLUGIN.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'add_person',
                data: 'john smith'
            },
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data);

            }

        });

    });

});
```

***PHP***

```
function add_a_person() {

    $data = array('abc' => 'xyz');
    wp_send_json($data);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_add_person', 'add_a_person');
```

I know that at the moment my PHP function doesn't do anything, but I was hoping that if I can just return a simple word, at least it's linked up.

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. How come the page is markup (HTML) is being returned to me instead of what I've defined as the data to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all your function name and action name do not match:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_person', 'add_a_person');
```

should be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_person', 'add_person');
```

and try adding a front end non logged action with:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_person', 'add_person');
```

Also, when using the wordpress ajax do not use `return` but use `echo`

```
function add_a_person() {

    // Just return this to test for now
    echo "hello";

}
```

That said as I was also told very recently you should consider using the WP REST API as it is much easier and cleaner

Comment: I added the `nopriv` action and made sure my function name was the same as the action name and it's still returning `0`. Nothing I try seems to do anything. I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: I had the same issue and ended using the rest api

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, refer below my solution and problems,

Problem : CSS wrote for wp-admin post list template by append in each page so this css code comes with each admin-ajax.php response as a on page style.

Solution : remove those styles and added as a admin enqueue script.

In your case may be some html or css may be added in page. So check with that scenario and deactivate any plugin relevant to this and check.

Answer (score -1):

You need to echo the value and exit, if you need json the function `wp_send_json()` will do what you are looking for.

```
function add_a_person() {
    wp_send_json( array('message'=> "hello") );
}
```

or

```
function add_a_person() {
    echo "hello";
    die();
}
```

Comment: I tried both methods but it still just returns the HTML of the page.

Comment: Hmm. I think your `MY_PLUGIN.ajax_url` js variable is wrong.  You're trying to make a request to /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php ? That should just return `0` by default.

Comment: So I should be making a request to admin-ajax.php? I'll try and hard code it in to see what happens.

Comment: I've updated the code above. I'm now getting a response of `0` when I click the button. So it's hitting the `admin-ajax.php` file. Doesn't seem to be returning my data though.